# Mobile facebook login - credentials provided by app settings

Tags: android, iphone, facebook

I managed to post status updates on facebook walls and log in via the following code:

```
facebook.authorize(this,
  new String[]{ "publish_checkins", "publish_stream"},
  new DialogListener() { /*crazy stuff here*/ }
);
```

My problem is the very first time logging in. Because it seems that the facebook is is not supporting logins from test accounts I can't talk about SSO but consider the "normal", web based, login screen popping up.

Is there a way get around this screen and let the application perform a login via username/email/password combination - provided the user is willing to handle this data to the applications.
E.g. something like `facebook.authorize(this, permArray, userName, password,`

I ask because I'm not sure if this is even possible at all, read: if fb API is providing hooks for this. I can imagine it is kinda security concern and thereby switched off.
In this case it would be cool if someone could provide a link to some documentation listing all possible login methods (not "all" but the important ones for smartphones) - this would definitely be helpful in the next meeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main document one should work with, in my opinion, when implementing the Authentication part for FB, is their [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) (for Android [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) one) - seems you're familiar with it. There you can see how **facebook** expects you to get logged in.
And [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/) (for Android [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/authentication/)) is the list of the methods they provide for these purposes.

To be shorter, NO, they don't have some simple function, which would allow you to do something you mentioned. Looks like you must use browser/their official app to login, in order to save cookies there; or you can use UIWebView to save them in your app.

I worked with FaceBook API some time ago and I didn't like it a lot. Perhaps this is because of the changes they've been doing lately in the API, but their documentation seems to be just immature; not speaking about their official example client (HackBook), which just doesn't work as expected (e.g. post video on the wall doesn't work).
Somehow even after reading carefully their documentation I had quite a lot of questions like what can be done with this API and what's forbidden at all.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the right documentation side. Also I agree it's painful to struggle one's way through the pages. Actually HackBook really cheered up our day around noon. We've never worked with it and when we tested the app we kind of realised it's probably not the best API done in history :) At least we achieved our goal and now can clearly line out what's possible and what is not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome, friend! :) Glad it was helpful!